# Prebuilt APK doesn't launch when preloaded but launches when installed on device

Tags: system-apps, android-10, aosp

I am working to integrate a vendor's prebuilt APKs onto my AOSP build Android 10.

The earlier versions used to work fine. The prebuilt APK was made as `certificate: platform` and `privileged: true`, making it a `system/priv-app` module. Suddenly, after a version upgrade, when we flash the system and launch the app, it doesn't launch and is stuck on the splash screen with no exception/errors/ANR traces in the logs, freshly flashed the system so there is not much memory consumption.

When tried `root`, `remount`, `rm` the prebuilt APK from `system/priv-app`, and installing the prebuilt APK, it worked fine. The app launches and is working fine.

Can someone help me find the root cause of the issue?

Note: It is a vendor's APK, so the code is not available, have to debug from the AOSP side.

Comment: Are you sure the app works at all. What happens if you just install the app as regular user app? If also nothing happens the app is most likely defect.

Comment: The app works fine when installed. So it goes in the data/app and works well